# Why import logging prints current date?

Tags: python, logging

I have a one-line code that imports logging. I don't expect it to print anything. However it prints the current date twice.

I have tried to google and search stackoverflow but haven't found similar questions.

My code is simply:

```
import logging
```

Expected result: nothing should happen

Actual results: Current date get printed

```
/usr/bin/python3.6 /home/user/.PyCharmCE2019.1/config/scratches/scratch_2.py
20190719
None
20190719
None

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The file is within pycharm scratches directory; there is not a file named `logging.py` in the directory.

Comment: Do you have a file named `logging.py` in the current directory?

Comment: does not happen in Spyder or the Anaconda Power Shell

Comment: Pretty sure it's not a core problem with `logging`. It'll be something to do with your specific installation.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because when a package is imported in a python file, that package file is first run and then imported.

Here's what you can try:

1) go to the logging package (wherever you installed it.)

2) find the main file

3) put all of the code of the main file under:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #all of the code
```

And then try importing.